# Toggle - Hide and show

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I copied w3schools hide and show toggle, but I want it to be reversed, so that the extra information isn't there from the beginning, but the button shows it.

This is the code:

html:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id="myDIV">
     This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

js:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want to have the `#myDIV` element have `display: none` (*makes it hidden*) initially rather that being shown at the start? Also I don't see any jQuery here, you don't need to add the tag.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your code, and what you posted [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xnvaz0aw/). Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @j08691 JavaScript, not jQuery my fault

Comment: At the top of your JS script, you can just say: ```document.getElementById('myDIV').style.display = "none";``` to set it as showing none from the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is simple: Just hide the div.

```
<div id="myDIV" style="display:none"> 
    This is my DIV element. 
</div>
```

---

Even cooler if you hide it in css instead:

```
<div id="myDIV"> 
    This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

And this in your css:

```
#myDIV {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd us a utility CSS class for this:

```
.is--hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can apply it to the element by default:

```
<button class="mybutton">Click Me</button>
<div class="example is--hidden">Some Text</div>
```

and toggle it via jQuery:

```
$('.mybutton').on('click', function () {
    $('.example').toggleClass('is--hidden');
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tL5mj54n/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add display : none in your code.

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id="myDIV" style="display:none;">
     This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No changes to styles or HTML required. Your javascript should be the following:

```
(function () {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display != 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'block';
   }
} )();

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
if (x.style.display != 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'block';
   }
};
```

The first function runs and hides your div and the second reacts to clicks and toggles the div.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet example

Set the style to hide the element (display:none) from the start. Toggle it on click.

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
  x.style.display = x.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

```html
<button id='myButton' >Click Me</button>

<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
     This is my DIV element.
</div>
```